# Overwrite resource definition in wrapper cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to overwrite a parent's resource in a wrapper cookbook and use it under the same name in the wrapper cookbook?
I want to customize nexus3 and nexus3_windows resources provided by nexus3 cookbook from the chef supermarket. nexus3 is defined in the resources/default.rb file and the nexus3_service is defined in resources/service_windows.rb file and exported with `provides :nexus3_service, os: 'windows'` clause. Can I customize and redefine them under their original names, so that I can refer to the customized resources using their original names, or is the only option to create my new resources under new names and change the references in my cookbook to use the new names?

Answer (score 0):

enclosed a quote from the [`edit_resource`](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#edit-resource) resource chef documenation.

> Use the `edit_resource` method to:
>
> > - Find a resource in the resource collection, and then edit it.
> > - Define a resource block. If a resource block with the same name exists in the resource collection, it will be updated with the contents of the resource block defined by the `edit_resource` method. If a resource block does not exist in the resource collection, it will be created.
> >
> > The syntax for the `edit_resource` method is as follows:
> >     `edit_resource(:resource_type, 'resource_name', resource_attrs_block)`

for more information, please head to chef documentation (link above).